# How to delegate ontap event in flutter to bottom widget in stack?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

If two containers completely overlap each other in stack then how do we detect `onTap()` event on bottom when widget at top is clicked?

***Use Case:***

My top container is transparent. I am using this transparent container tap to animate top widgets (this top widget sticks at the bottom of the sceen). And on tap I want to animate same bottom element at position.

[image]

Additianly I implemented custom Rawgesture but i don't see gesture arena conflicts. This arena conflicts are only detected if elements are positioned such that one is parent and second is child.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Stack(children: <Widget>[
        GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            print('green clicked.');
          },
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.green,
            width: 400,
            height: 400,
          ),
        ),
        GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            print('red clicked.');
          },
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.red,
            width: 200,
            height: 200,
          ),
        ),
      ]),
    );
  }
}
```

In this above example When I click on red container it will print `red clicked` but there is some part of green container is also present. I want to know if both events can be called?

Thanks.

Comment: Try changing hitTestBehavior of the top widget

Comment: @Pavel that was my first thing i did. But didn't worked.

Comment: If you want to get pressed of bottom container item, you have to make upper container color as transparent. It sometime depends, like the upper container consists text, and below container containes some image, than you can get the text pressed (if any event is there) only on the text font area, and except this you can get the event of lower image event if you have keep background color of text transparent.

Comment: @SanketVekariya My top container is transparent. I am using this transparent container tap to animate top widgets. Also on tap I want to animate same bottom element. Also I implemented custom Rawgesture but i don't see gesture arena conflicts so couldn't figure out what's going on. I have made workaround but wanted to know if its possible.

Comment: can you share us an example "run able code" ? to understand more about , so we can help

Comment: @abdalmonem will do

Comment: @abdalmonem I added the example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no direct way to know if there is an underlying widget where user has tapped. However, I ran your code of red and green containers and achieved it with `onTapDown` event

Simplest solution (without onTapDown) ::

Added a following function :

```
void onGreenClick()
  {
    print("Green clicked");
  }
```

Changed Green's onTap handler as :

```
onTap: onGreenClick,
```

And added onGreenClick() in Red's onTap as :

```
onTap: () {
            print('red clicked.');
            onGreenClick();
          },
```

However, as you guess this will work only when the widgets are completely overlap on each other. In case, there's some area where red container is present but not green then above would fail. To, achieve that, you use `onTapDown` as below :

Add onTapDown handler to both red and green (under GestureDetector) as :

```
onTapDown: (TapDownDetails details) => onTapDown(context, details),
```

where the handler function is  :

```
void onTapDown(BuildContext context, TapDownDetails details) {
    print('${details.globalPosition}');
    final RenderBox box = context.findRenderObject();
    final Offset localOffset = box.globalToLocal(details.globalPosition);
    setState(() {
      posx = localOffset.dx;
      posy = localOffset.dy;
    });
    if (posx < 100.0 && posy < 100.0) onGreenClick();
  }
```

Now, if you see the last line, we call onGreenClick only on the specific x,y-coordinates.

Thus the end result is you get "Green click" in the debug output window even on clicking on red.

The entire code is available [here](https://pastebin.com/Yx3WVJTj)

Comment: I tried this workaround. Here is problem with `tapDown` i have to do so many hoops with `tapDown` to figure out if its just `tapdown` or drag and any other events which can trigger `tapDown`. if you do a long press then its still a `tapdown`, so on and on...

Comment: in my app green and red containers has `Twins` so on red tap both needs to animated. Also I have other gestures also like long press, double tap, swipe also i am using tapdown for edge clicks and so on..... If you know any easy way to achieve all of this that will also help a lot.

Comment: I guess I get it except -if on red tap both needs to be animated then you don't need onTapDown; why don't you simply call `onGreenClicked()` from `onRedClicked()` ('simplest solution' as mentioned above ?

Comment: Yup. That's current approach. I have shared class where all the events are redirected and that makes call. I just wanted to know if there is another way to do this. I have many widgets which does similar things.

Comment: I gave a thought about it since yesterday. And in my opinion, this (current/answered) approach is better. Because A. It is simple. B. Flexible and yet easy to maintain and more importantly C. You will be in total control all the time and D. Future proof i.e. if a requirement change tomorrow like don’t call onGreenClicked in all the circumstances then it will be quite easy to adopt. ....just my two cents. :-)

Comment: Its good to know someone agrees with the design. I just wanted to be sure I am not missing anything. Thanks. I will reward the bounty to you at the end of the period.